# Why column facet in Vega Lite not working properly with layer?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I'm trying to create 3 column plot and it works when there's no layer.

[image]

But when I add the layer - 3 columns get merged into one plot ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBECmB2DGB7AJgS1gc0gLjKCEkSANgK4C2sOeUAZqtMctZMqQE4CGALqolQBoo3AJ4AHaC1iJy6TsUhgAvgJDgCkAB7VgdBkxYAjdAH1UkIZFESWidmljzFS9SvWRinEdHbUA2uoQ+ASE5JzsANY6wuKSuJCG4RZQAM6oAF5xYABMyqohhHBIDli4wQVQItGQ9IzM8bKCMTbxAI6knLC83DyoAG6SeYEFkCLZ1bUGDZzaltZZkO2d3b0DzsMQLiFuIeUaYZHV8yy88FFDFTAIKOileBsaVWV6dSzk0J3JVrEsS12oPV4a2UDy2BDBAF18lBkDxODphpA+vJSNAUv4HnsQglTOZcABGaGXNhcXj8aiEh6hGYUgB0AE4AGwAFmyAA4AMwAVgA7PSOTz8Wz8YyuUSRu9PgTaQAGHnCjmMwWMtlM7LZFXi7GNagy2kc-GG4Vstks+nZHnM5ls0Fa+4VQjGWBmajZO2EEm9ckE91QMLaaXy7Jc1Vsrnm0Vc1kc32QSVUaUyxUi5kctPZQ1ci2Uh1+9C6-Xc+n05lJ9lsmXqllc22YqlQJ0u3Ax+usDhehNgHMOuM06WM-mMtNZq3Mrkytk82Pxgv0tnMkUy0Xq-HZc3s6f53B6rM8i0c9kDg3h7LM2sVLEaRt4sDM2Oesmd7uXf10rm8g9h7P4mUy5l76cPifWULUrel8QXLlRUgxlN07Hch2tSck0ncM0zPCodgKS9HVxagxVbB8+Cfac+y7Wl8XlRlK1FDlKx-FtczjICC1VEMINNecIxFWDWx1bdaRPLlPy5SjgxLRlGXPbDW2vCl73bR9qEYntX1wbJBNNK0TX-DkFWZXimJnaU1xLPkSxlelwwg9U4ILSik3A1l6R5OVORTaTdlkvD1IU0liOU0iAzADl9R5blKwrJDVxUl8WOlRU9OtQUl1ZFlnwlLcwD1IVrRlSjVQ5cC9wXHlPIIHCGx8kK-I7QK+LIjTuTTByBQ5Ut505QCpWy2lkJaudOTakM7z4rKcoM09-0ZEUhSFekl3KoJvOdG9RqYojvRqhrgvxQThL3d8XJ5S0Nz4+Leos1yxxOxkM3DdbVPGwSf1VfEBVTGVxxVKTMLtSqcVW-DaqU5sgtnJdwvZfEFu5JVrW6+DBNOyyvssmGXLDOyBIMorsj0r7Q25SilvtHs5J9QjFIC3ACKMsjmVpYMWWyCdZqK96Mu1C69vfCDKKHX9uU5Vlsd6i0wxOkV8ch39foKLCvKYimchBmmwDp1SGdpcLK1ZVNRPavS2URul+VXcDxzZdlf35ekxb1C0mU66C8tXGs-rrZXqtikZNs7TWXzIvaKz3MTeXVRVjtNgSoPxw7JytPHbLGpHmaZST8Y1KNSzHUmAZVx7iWprbA4lMi9UnfkBXR06oOtmPeurK0LZm83UId2lIPDVV5XCrM13zlamw1tXS-BgSWVLJd3utuiLUM1SLp3fG03nDMRS0+dO4+wUjcVZli0tKDQWGCFXBAJQgA)).

[image]

**How to make it to be separated into 3 columns by the `duration` field?**

**CODE**

For the plot with the full data please use editor link above.

```
{
  "encoding": {
    "column": { "field": "duration", "type": "nominal" },

    "x": { "field": "bin_i", "type": "ordinal" }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": { "type": "bar", "size": 2 },
      "encoding": {
        "y": { "field": "min", "type": "quantitative" },
        "y2": { "field": "max", "type": "quantitative" }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": { "type": "tick" },
      "encoding": {
        "y": { "field": "mean", "type": "quantitative" }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "bin_i": 1,
        "duration": 1,
        "max": 1.9642835793718165,
        "mean": 1.0781367168962268,
        "min": 0.3111818864927448
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A layered chart does not accept a faceted encoding. If you want to facet a layered chart, you should use the [`facet` operator](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/facet.html#facet-operator) rather than a facet encoding.

For your example, it would look like this ([Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEBmCGDGBTALpAXGYl4HsA2ArgLYB26mMAlongCbmS0EBOsylOZANFMgJ4AHRAxI4ilErDyQAvjK7goAZyHxyoCBEiISuWhIDm6xZqgAPdVRr0MkAEYSA+pUg9I-IQxzN9k6TJMweUDIPFg+RGZyAG1AiA1TTUgiWGYAa0sPYVs7VNdlSgAvbLAAJmDEpJ09Q2NK0zjEyD5LaGo6BnFuXkESyABHAlgSdmQ2SgA3YQr6rT5S1vabKBSLANn1xJnTBMrk1IyMLCyGdngM7abqnF8jI8bTZsXrTsRh-PdehkHh0fGp2QPIKNTYQAC6ihmjDYsDqSQmUgIiCUMUauyaDhIznIAEYFLNGCxxpxcfj6vsLBgcQA6ACcADYACylAAcAGYAKwAdlpbK5OJZOPpHLJeyIbzIVOpAAYuYK2fT+fSWQzSqVlaKml1yNLqWycQbBSyWUzaaUuYzGSyQZr4kD7E4XBhSrakkxWOwSVTXVpVrjqXLShyVSyOWbhRzmWyfSsJf7pQqhYy2SnSgaOea8fbtRhdSmw7TGQnWSzpWqmRybWj7ZjsRho-b3cTJWAswS-VL6bz6fnSpbGRzpSyuTHknHc3SWYyhdLhWqcaUzazRzmwLqM1zzWzWV39WG+1XKujHrWnWBGaOm56W23yR3W9SOdzt6HMzjpdLGZuV+OH2WuWWtI4tOHLCiB9IrhIOqPj2VrDgmw5himjKHokx5JKe5Aio2RLXqS2awJSD44nK9JlsKbJlu+Dbtr+uoqsGwEmlO4ZChB2ZQRO+4ci+HIkUGhb0vSqE7DWjr4QSV4cC2NF3oR5ClI+JqWsaX5svKjLsbR7xSouhY8oW0q0mGwFqpBLa6iRCZAcytIAXK+pMiJmjoVomHOpeuHSeQslivJ9Z6lynJlqWcELr5Wq-jSCrqVa-KzsyTK3mKnFrtSApWtKJEqmyQGbtOXLOXaBLuWAEWPFJXplSu-llHqPH6gBfJskWU7sj+OlpfBKY4rSxopkFwYXhxFnpZpfZfvSQoCgKtKzkVmBiViZ7DZJXlVeVST3jST58kGYZcodzIsh1o2GQBA6HfSaZhqtd6peu74qjifLJtKg7KsJlSXMV5Kldha0et59Y1URupzYqL69QmoEWid2Z0Y+FqlEZ71Gb1dmhuZ0GablpTqe9IaciRC2uVApXJU0lUtgDclEYy1JBkyKOClNuUvZTjzip1O18QVPYfpy7LMtjE7mqGh1Cvjs4AfN32umTDrLQpnlA1VtN+fTAaUX2fbEy16nw9pN50vqi44oOLKsh+vK0qLaXmgybVgZlC6VvL1YleJIM4WrNOg-6pabvx3JqgqdkjgjnXrtde3BhayZLi6I3QUzDJCfj6qRkWA6k0tdbnqrzZYQHE7DryfLo8joFW6d0EVpaC4Mr1+qIfbuogWGKpyoNaq0nnXvKxgGtU+t-sEWD1JMkWs4vVbOtclpd6IxmKaxWmQrKVO7eBV+L3JgqjK0nZA5fVsgQQhAAQyEAA)):

```
{
  "facet": {"column": {"field": "duration", "type": "nominal"}},
  "spec": {
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"field": "bin_i", "type": "ordinal"}
    },
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "size": 2},
        "encoding": {

          "y": {"field": "min", "type": "quantitative"},
          "y2": {"field": "max"}
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "tick"},
        "encoding": {
          "y": {"field": "mean", "type": "quantitative"}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "bin_i": 1,
        "duration": 1,
        "max": 1.9642835793718165,
        "mean": 1.0781367168962268,
        "min": 0.3111818864927448
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]